# Want to pass a parameterized enum to a function using _ as parameter (like my_fun(MyEnum::Type(_)))

Tags: rust

I have this `next_expected_kind` method that return the next item of an `Iterable<Kind>` if it is the expected type, or an error if not.
It works fine for non parameterized types like `Kind1`, but I don't know how to use it if the type that needs parameters like `Kind2`.

Something like:

```rust
let _val = match s.next_expected_kind(Kind::Kind2(str)) {
    Ok(k) => str,
    _ => panic!("error"),
};
```

Is there any tricky to make it?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d21d5cff42fcca633e95b4915ce2bf1d

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Kind {
    Kind1,
    Kind2(String),
}

struct S {
    kinds: std::vec::IntoIter<Kind>,
}

impl S {
    fn next_expected_kind(&mut self, expected: Kind) -> Result<Kind, &str> {
        match self.kinds.next() {
            Some(k) if k == expected => Ok(k),
            _ => Err("not expected"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S {
        kinds: vec![Kind::Kind1, Kind::Kind2(String::from("2"))].into_iter(),
    };
    _ = s.next_expected_kind(Kind::Kind1);

    // let _val = s.next_expected_kind(Kind::Kind2(str));
    let _val = match s.kinds.next() {
        Some(Kind::Kind2(str)) => str,
        _ => panic!("not expected"),
    };
}
```

Comment: How about passing a callback function, like `|val| matches!(val, Kind::Kind2(_))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::mem::discriminant()` like this:

```rust
use std::mem::{Discriminant, discriminant};
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Kind {
    Kind1,
    Kind2(String),
}

struct S {
    kinds: std::vec::IntoIter<Kind>,
}

impl S {
    fn next_expected_kind(&mut self, expected: Discriminant<Kind>) -> Result<Kind, &str> {
        match self.kinds.next() {
            Some(k) if discriminant(&k) == expected => Ok(k),
            _ => Err("not expected"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S {
        kinds: vec![Kind::Kind1, Kind::Kind2(String::from("2"))].into_iter(),
    };
    _ = dbg!(s.next_expected_kind(discriminant(&Kind::Kind1)));

    let _val = dbg!(s.next_expected_kind(discriminant(&Kind::Kind2(String::new()))));
}
```

The obvious drawback being that you'll have to create an instance with "empty" or default data wherever you want to call it.

---

The only other way I can think of would be to write a macro since you can't pass just the "variant" of an enum around.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Kind {
    Kind1(String),
    Kind2(i32, i32),
}

struct S {
    kinds: std::vec::IntoIter<Kind>,
}

macro_rules! next_expected_kind {
    ($self:expr, $expected:path) => {
        match $self.kinds.next() {
            Some(k) if matches!(k, $expected(..)) => Ok(k),
            _ => Err("not expected"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = S {
        kinds: vec![Kind::Kind1(String::from("1")), Kind::Kind2(2,3)].into_iter(),
    };
    _ = dbg!(next_expected_kind!(&mut s, Kind::Kind1));

    let _val = dbg!(next_expected_kind!(&mut s, Kind::Kind2));
}
```

Note: this has the limitation that all variants have to be tuple variants or struct variants and it's a bit clunky to use.

Comment: Better, take `Discriminant<Kind>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, I changed it.